# Pac4j Editing Configuration of a Client Based on UI

Tags: java, servlets, pac4j

I am Using Pac4j 5.0X with Java 8 Jee Project which is maven based.
For reference:: https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/tree/5.0.x
In this ,I am using Webservlet for editing the Config changees

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/customScopes")
public class CustomScopesServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
   Integer counter=0;
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        OidcConfiguration oidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();
        oidcConfiguration.setClientId("");
        oidcConfiguration.setSecret("");
        oidcConfiguration.setUseNonce(false);
        DemoConfigFactory.CONFIG_INSTANCE.getClients().getClients().forEach(client -> {
            try {
                counter++;
                if (client instanceof GoogleOidcClient) {
                    ((GoogleOidcClient) client).setConfiguration(oidcConfiguration);
                    String name = client.getName();
                     if(counter==1)
                      ((GoogleOidcClient) client).getConfiguration().setScope("openid profile");
                     else if(counter>1)
                      ((GoogleOidcClient) client).getConfiguration().setScope("openid");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is a Sample Test where i am modifying the DemoconfigFaactory
When i restart my app, the default one is loaded and i can see authorize call sent openid  as default scope, when i hit  customScopes servlet the scopes are now set to openid profile and it #refecte's in the application , [The Default Scopes is Openid ], now the second time i hit the #endpoint again the scopes is not changed scopes which was openid profile ,should now be openid #vbut i cant see the auth endpoint to send openid it still refects openid profile while loggig in.

Whenever i change my configuration from the UI the configs should be updated accordingly each time.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that, I mean, changing configuration over time.

Either you need two `GoogleOidcClient` with different scopes or you need a customisation in the code.

Comment: Hi jleleu, Can you please guide  me on the customisation that I can add for this it would be really helpful...

Comment: Sure. The `OidcRedirectionActionBuilder` is the internal component responsible for redirecting to the OIDC server. You should create a new class inheriting from it and overriding the `buildParams` method to change the scope. And you should set it to the `GoogleOidcClient` using the `setRedirectionActionBuilder` method.

Comment: Thanks, for your rply , what about the configuration properties like authorization url that we sent in oidcconfiguration? can you please help me on this

Comment: By creating a new `CustomOidcRedirectionActionBuilder` inheriting from `OidcRedirectionActionBuilder` and by only overriding the `buildParams` method, you would keep the provided configuration and add your specific logic: you should certainly call `super.buildParams` and do something around `authParams.put(OidcConfiguration.SCOPE, configContext.getScope());`.

Comment: Hii Jleleu, thanks for your reply i was actually looking for Coniguration changes too , not only scopes and custome parameters but also configuration like url changes like token URL or Discovery URL..How can we do it in our application..

Comment: If you had many changes to do, it is certainly better to have two different clients and their configurations. You should then override the `DefaultSecurityClientFinder` to switch from one to the other one.